# How to Implement User-Adjustable Timing for Relay Switches with Arduino?

Tags: arduino, embedded

I'm working on an Arduino project to manage the timing of relay switches, consisting of 4 relays, 3 push buttons, and a 7-segment display. While I've completed the setup, I'm struggling to design a system where the user can adjust the on/off durations of the relays using three push buttons and the 7-segment display. Below is my code:

```
#define CLK 2
#define DIO 3
TM1637Display display(CLK, DIO);

int relayPins[] = {4, 5, 6, 7};
int onTimes[] = {2000, 4000, 5000, 3000};
int offTimes[] = {1000, 2000, 1000, 3000};

void setup() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    pinMode(relayPins[i], OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(relayPins[i], LOW);
  }
  display.setBrightness(0x0f);
}

void loop() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    digitalWrite(relayPins[i], HIGH);
    for (int j = onTimes[i] / 1000; j > 0; j--) {
      display.showNumberDec(j, false, 2, 0);
      delay(1000);
    }
    digitalWrite(relayPins[i], LOW);
    for (int j = offTimes[i] / 1000; j > 0; j--) {
      display.showNumberDec(j, false, 2, 0);
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
}
```

I need assistance in implementing a mechanism where the user can adjust the on/off durations of each relay using the push buttons and display. How can I modify this code to achieve that?

In attempting to modify the variables for user-adjustable timing, I initially tried to integrate additional functions to read the state of the push buttons and update the onTimes[] and offTimes[] arrays accordingly. However, I encountered difficulties in properly synchronizing the button inputs with the timing intervals for each relay. Specifically, I struggled with efficiently updating the timing variables based on user input while ensuring smooth relay operation and display updates. I expected to successfully implement a system where the user could interactively adjust the timing durations using the push buttons and observe the changes reflected on the 7-segment display

Comment: Like [your former question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77900128/11294831) this one lacks focus. Especially the source has not changed. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. This site is not a forum and is therefore not well suited to teach you how to learn a serious development process and C++, which is the programming language on Arduinos. You might need to step back and divide your project in smaller tasks that you can investigate easier.

Comment: You need at least to define how the UI will work - what are the button functions, what does the display show, how do you select a relay, how do you select in or off time adjustment, are the relays asynchronous to each other.  Essentially you are asking for a design, not a solution to a discrete problem, so not an ideal SO question.  The Arduino framework makes some design decisions for you.  It is appropriate for finite state-machine, and you need to loose the delays.  Instead poll time elapsed and trigger state changes in time.

Answer (score 0):

To make the Arduino "big-loop" framework work effectively you should break down your design into separate *non-blocking* state-machines.  Certainly you should avoid blocking `delay()` calls if you want to be able to concurrently process relay switching and the user interaction.

In fact your existing implementation is broken in any event since it performs the on-off-toggle of each relay sequentially, so the off time for each relay will be the sum of the on+off time of the other three relays.

If you change your `loop()` function as follows:

```cpp
void loop() 
{
  relay_statemachine() ;
  ui_statemachine() ;
}
```

Then a `relay_statemachine()` implementation that runs all four relay on-off-cycles concurrently and does not block (i.e always returns immediately so that the `ui_statemachine()` can run) might look like:

```cpp
void relay_statemachine()
{
  static struct
  {
    int state ;     // current relay state
    int timestamp ; // time of last relay state change
  } relay[] = { 0 } ;

  // Current time
  unsigned long now = millis() ;
  
  // For each relay
  for( int r = 0; r < 4; r++ )
  {
    // If relay is off...
    if( relay[r].state == LOW )
    {
      // ... if it is time to switch ...
      if( now - relay[r].timestamp > offTimes[r] )
      {
         // ... change state and timestamp it
        relay[r].state = HIGH ;
        relay[r].timestamp = now ;
      }
    }
    else // ... else relay is on...
    {
      // ... if it is time to switch ...
      if( now - relay[r].timestamp > onTimes[r] )
      {
         // ... change state and timestamp it
        relay[r].state = LOW ;
        relay[r].timestamp = now ;
      }
    }

    // Assert current relay state.
    digitalWrite (relayPins[r], relay[r].state ) ;
  }
}
```

You would then similarly implement `ui_statemachine()` as a state-machine (with no delays or blocking), where the triggers are button events (do not forget the need to debounce).  You have not defined how the UI will work, but I suggest:

- Button A - select function cyclically:

  1. Relay 1 ON time  (display 1.1)
  2. Relay 1 OFF time (display 1.0)
  3. Relay 2 ON time  (display 2.1)
  4. Relay 2 OFF time (display 2.0)
  5. Relay 3 ON time  (display 3.1)
  6. Relay 3 OFF time (display 3.0)
  7. Relay 4 ON time  (display 4.1)
  8. Relay 4 OFF time (display 4.0)

- Button B - Increment time for currently selected function (display time)
- Button C - Decrement time for currently selected function (display time)

You might further display the current relay state after there have been no button presses for a period of time.  For example (`1001` when R1 and R4 are on and R2 and and R3 are off).

Comment: It sounds like a good solution, but I need to adjust a total of 8 numerical variables (the active time for each of the four relays and the time intervals between them) using a maximum of 5 push buttons. Additionally, I plan to add a rotary encoder later. This has made the task challenging for me :(

Comment: You say 3 push-buttons in your question not 5.  The above solution uses three as you requested, so what is the problem?

Comment: In this message, I explained the continuation of the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77940877/23315161

Comment: @JafarFarganlooj. it seems perhaps that you have misunderstood this answer.  It _replaces_ your code not _augments_ it.  It does not provide the _new_ code you need to implement the UI because that is ill defined, and you provided no I/O details for the buttons in any case.  Feel free to use my design, or specify your own - preferably in a new question.